# Printing data from multiple json file into single html table by validating the condition

Tags: javascript, html, json

As I am new to JS and JSON, I am having tough time to find a proper solution that works for me. I have two different json files. First one : `players.json` with following data:

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "id": 109191123,
            "surname": "Farah",
            "full_name": "Robbie Farah",
            "short_name": "R. Farah",
            "other_names": "Robert",
            "jumper_number": 9,
            "position_code": "CEN1",
            "position_order": 9,
            "position_description": "Hooker",
            "is_captain": false,
            "is_interchange": false
        },
        {
            "id": 109509,
            "surname": "Rapana",
            "full_name": "Jordan Rapana",
            "short_name": "J. Rapana",
            "other_names": "Jordan",
            "jumper_number": 1,
            "position_code": "FBCK",
            "position_order": 1,
            "position_description": "Full Back",
            "is_captain": false,
            "is_interchange": false
        },
        {
            "id": 111285,
            "surname": "Waqa",
            "full_name": "Sisa Waqa",
            "short_name": "S. Waqa",
            "other_names": "Sisa",
            "jumper_number": 2,
            "position_code": "WING1",
            "position_order": 2,
            "position_description": "Wing",
            "is_captain": false,
            "is_interchange": false
        },
        {
            "id": 109861,
            "surname": "Croker",
            "full_name": "Jarrod Croker",
            "short_name": "J. Croker",
            "other_names": "Jarrod",
            "jumper_number": 3,
            "position_code": "CEN1",
            "position_order": 3,
            "position_description": "Centre",
            "is_captain": true,
            "is_interchange": false
        },
        {
            "id": 112814,
            "surname": "Lee",
            "full_name": "Edrick Lee",
            "short_name": "E. Lee",
            "other_names": "Edrick",
            "jumper_number": 5,
            "position_code": "CEN2",
            "position_order": 4,
            "position_description": "Centre",
            "is_captain": false,
            "is_interchange": false
        }
    ]
}
```

and similarly, second one is `stats.json` having following json code

```
{
    "player_stats": [
        {
            "id": 112814,
            "matches": "123",
            "tries": "11"
        },
        {
            "id": 111285,
            "matches": "234",
            "tries": "22"
        },
        {
            "id": 109861,
            "matches": "345",
            "tries": "33"
        },
        {
            "id": 109509,
            "matches": "456",
            "tries": "44"
        },
        {
            "id": 109510,
            "matches": "567",
            "tries": "55"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is parse the JSON files and display their data using a table, using the `short_name`, `matches`, and `tries` fields. If a player does not have stats then just ignore them and print only those with stats.

How can I print something like below: If `id` on players matches with `id` on stats, then I have to print stats like below. Couldn't even start. Any hint or answer would be great help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry couldn't see your image as it was blocked but.

can you just do a nested loop? (probably a fancier way with reduce but this seems to work)

loop through the players and add in their stats with the filter function.

then filter out players that do not have stats again with filter function.

then do a nested loop to create the table.

run code snippet below

```js
const players = {players: [{
    "id": 109191123,
    "surname": "Farah",
    "full_name": "Robbie Farah",
    "short_name": "R. Farah",
    "other_names": "Robert",
    "jumper_number": 9,
    "position_code": "WING1",
    "position_order": 2,
    "position_description": "Wing",
    "is_captain": false,
    "is_interchange": false
  },
  {
    "id": 109861,
    "surname": "Croker",
    "full_name": "Jarrod Croker",
    "short_name": "J. Croker",
    "other_names": "Jarrod",
    "jumper_number": 3,
    "position_code": "CEN1",
    "position_order": 3,
    "position_description": "Centre",
    "is_captain": true,
    "is_interchange": false
  },
  {
    "id": 112814,
    "surname": "Lee",
    "full_name": "Edrick Lee",
    "short_name": "E. Lee",
    "other_names": "Edrick",
    "jumper_number": 5,
    "position_code": "CEN2",
    "position_order": 4,
    "position_description": "Centre",
    "is_captain": false,
    "is_interchange": false
  }
]}

const stats = {player_stats : [{
    "id": 112814,
    "matches": "123",
    "tries": "11"
  },
  {
    "id": 111285,
    "matches": "234",
    "tries": "22"
  },
  {
    "id": 109861,
    "matches": "345",
    "tries": "33"
  },
  {
    "id": 109509,
    "matches": "456",
    "tries": "44"
  },
  {
    "id": 109510,
    "matches": "567",
    "tries": "55"
  }
]}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.apple').append(` <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Short Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Matches</th>
          <th scope="col">Tries</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="mybody">

      </tbody>
    </table>`);
  let myhtml = '';
  players.players.forEach(function(element) {
    element.player_stats = stats.player_stats.filter(x => x.id === element.id);
  });
  players.players.filter(x => x.player_stats.length).forEach(function(element) {
    element.player_stats.forEach(function(stat) {
      myhtml += `<tr>
             <td>${element.short_name}</td>
              <td>${stat.matches}</td>
               <td>${stat.tries}</td>
             </tr>`
    });
  });
  $('#mybody').append(myhtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="apple"></div>
```

Comment: It works but can it be done without altering json file and html ? I mean, I don't want to alter json and html but want to create table dynamically only using js or jquery. I have div with class name of TableSpace, on .html file, inside which I am going to print table.

Comment: I don't think you need to modify anything just use the name of your data. like instead of players yours is probably players.players and your second one is probably stats.player_stats. so whatever you have your data named

Comment: I couldn't find updated one. I think my question is unclear. I have 2 .json files, 1 .html file and one .js file . Whatever i have to do is edit only .js file. so, i have empty div with  class name of apple  on .html file, i have to output table inside that div without adding any extra html for table column like you did on your answer.

Comment: ok I edited answer again. just append the table html to your apple div first.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you again. Out of 5 id on players:  112814,109861, 111285, 109509 and 109191123. 
The id with 112814,111285,109861,109509 matches. But from the code provided by you, prints only two value with id of 109861 and 112814. I couldn't find where is error.

Comment: I don't know what this means

Comment: I have edited my above comment. It prints only 2 output insted of 4.